# julia: how to use optional arguments for an anonymous function

Tags: function, types, julia, optional-arguments

[Here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/functions/#optional-arguments) is the doc of Julia.

It says that we could set optional arguments for the functions of Julia. For example,

```
function parse(type, num, base=10)
    ###
end
```

Then we can call the function `parse` like this:

```
parse(Int,"12",3)
parse(Int,"12")
```

I've tested it and it did work.

Now I want to do the same thing for a function in a type. Here is an example,

```
type MyTest

  testShow::Function

  function MyTest()
    this = new()

    this.testShow = function(p1, p2 = 1, p3 = 2)
    end

    return this
  end

end
```

But I get an error:

> ERROR: LoadError: syntax: "p2=1" is not a valid function argument name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Reza said, anonymous functions do not support keyword arguments. So I tried to do this:

```
type MyTest

  testShow::Function

  function MyTest()
    this = new()

    this.testShow = function tt(p1, p2 = 1, p3 = 2)
    end

    return this
  end

end
```

I set a name `tt` to the anonymous function. It works although `tt` is never used.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be trying to imitate the way that other object-oriented languages (e.g. Python) do things. However, this is not how Julia works: methods (functions) *do not* live inside types in Julia.

Rather, methods live *outside* types. For example:

```
type MyTest
    value::Int
end

function my_show(x::MyTest, p1, p2=1, p3=2)
    x.value * p1 * p2 * p3
end

x = MyTest(10)

println(my_show(x, 3))
println(my_show(x, 3, 3, 3))
```

This is a different paradigm from other languages, and it does not make sense to try to force Julia to behave like other languages. There are lots of discussions on the julia-users mailing list about this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. In fact I have to force Julia to OOP. Here is something that I found: https://thenewphalls.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/understanding-object-oriented-programming-in-julia-part-1/

Comment: I have to because my colleague do his job expecting a OOP module. I have no choice.

Comment: Julia's OOP is a generalization of *tradicional* OOP, ie. in Python: `x.foo(y)`; in Julia `foo(x, y)`. But Python is actually also doing `foo(x, y)` it's just that with simple dispatch `x` in this case is special and owns the method (`x.foo(y)` is just syntactic sugar). As Julia have multiple dispatch this makes no sense.

Comment: ie. in Python, this:`"test".upper() # => 'TEST'` is syntactic sugar for: `upper = str.upper; upper("test") # => 'TEST'`

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions and named functions are different, e.g. anonymous functions do not support keyword arguments, and they are non-generic. [ref](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2773)

```
julia> (x,y=0)->x
ERROR: syntax: "y=0" is not a valid function argument name
```

Comment: as @David P. Sanders already mentioned, it's better no to think of Julia-Lang types like object-oriented classes, and also it's better not to try implement member functions like this.